# Is there a permission to check the number of touch points a device can handle at once?

Tags: android, events, touch, multi-touch

I'm working on an app that needs to be able to handle up to 5 simultaneous touch events (essentially a click with all 5 fingers at once, anywhere on the screen), but I realized that my testing device (HTC Rezound, 4.0.3) can only handle 4 touches at a time.

I know that other android devices can handle at least 5, so **is there a permission or something that I can add to my AndroidManifest to make sure that a device can handle 5 touches**?  The reason for this would be to make sure that certain devices that can't handle the touches won't be allowed to install the app (because obviously it won't work correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html there is talk of:

```
android.hardware.faketouch.multitouch.jazzhand
android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand
```

which mentions requiring 5 touch points.
So I believe you would do this in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Just added the android:required part, which you would want to ensure no one can download the app who cannot use 5 point multitouch.